# Windows 8 gives "system thread exception not handled" error message after update

Tags: windows-8, bsod, amd-radeon

I have a 64-bit Dell laptop which I recently upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 8. Since then, it's creating havoc in my life. The Metro apps are not working, the system crashes once in a while, and none of my games are running because I don't have the correct drivers for my ATI 5000 series graphics card.

Some days back, Windows downloaded an update and prompted me to restart. After that day, whenever I log in and fire up my desktop, I get all kinds of blue screen errors. The most common one looks something like this:

```
- SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED.
```

Please tell me how I can fix this, optionally how to go back to Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

While the update path between Windows 7 and Windows 8 is ideally smooth, I've personally found that there can be unexpected driver issues that pop up all over the place. As a personal recommendation, I suggest backing up your data, formatting the drive and then a clean install.

Depending on your installation media (CD/DVD or USB), the path you take to install Windows 8 will be slightly different.

If you have the ISO file from Microsoft (or have the DVD and want to create an ISO file), [About.com](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/install-windows-8-usb.htm) has an excellent tutorial that you can follow. They use the [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool](http://images2.store.microsoft.com/prod/clustera/framework/w7udt/1.0/en-us/Windows7-USB-DVD-tool.exe) to mount the ISO on a flash drive.

For a clean install tutorial, the same author has another [guide](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/ss/windows-8-clean-install-part-1.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You should install a fresh copy of windows 8 than upgrading windows 7. Also, Dell has released drivers for win 8 now. Use those.

Comment: Windows upgrade from 7 to 8 is really smooth in fact microsoft seems to be encouraging people to upgrade from their existing version.
I can personally vouch for the seamless transition to windows 8

Comment: Can you explain how to do it?

Comment: @Shobhit: For a clean install if you have Windows already on the drive, you can use the USB/ISO media the Update Assistant allowed you to create. Or you can buy and use the Upgrade DVD. For installing on a bare hard drive, you need the costlier OEM/System Builder version of Windows 8.

Comment: I was looking for something like step by step instructions..